symfony 6.4 how to read serializer groups dynamically?
I am changing from annotation to attributes and have trouble to get my serializer groups.
I annotate properties in my data classes (not Entities) like this:
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class Foo()
{

    #[Groups(['view', 'create', 'update'])]
    public ?string $author = '';

and in the matching Controller:

class FooController()
{
    #[
        Route(path: '/all', name: 'collection_paged', methods: ['GET']),
        ViewContext(['groups' => ['collection'], 'view_link' => false]),
        Groups(['collection']),
        OA\Get(
            operationId: 'foo_collection_paged',
            summary: 'Collection of foos',
            tags: ['Foo Data']
        )
    ]
    public function collectionPaged(Request $request): PagedView
    {
        $filterCollection = ParamToFilterHelper::convertToFilter($request);
        $searchResult = $this->searchService->getCollection($filterCollection);

        return $this->createPagedCollectionView($searchResult);
    }



I have an event subscriber and managed there to get the author property excluded in the output since it hasn't got the group "collection":

    private function setEventResponse(ViewEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $context = (new ObjectNormalizerContextBuilder())
            ->withGroups('collection')
            ->toArray();

        $controllerData = $event->getControllerResult();
        $headers = [];
        $data = [];

        if ($controllerData instanceof ViewInterface) {
            $data = $controllerData->getData();
            $code = $controllerData->getStatusCode();
            $headers = $controllerData->getHeader();
        }

        $normalizedData = $this->serializer->normalize($data, 'json', $context);
        $response = JsonResponse::fromJsonString(
            json_encode($normalizedData),
            $code,
            $headers
        );

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

What I didn't manage yet is to read the Groups / SerializationGroups of the different controller methods. As you can see I have currently statically 'collection' there.
How can I read my group array dynamically?
I am using Symfony 6.4 and php 8.2
